# Elasticsearch Java 8.5: retrieve all Ids

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve all  (elasticsearch) Ids of an index using the following code.

```
    SearchRequest sr = SearchRequest.of(r -> r
        .index("my_index")
        .source(s -> s.fetch(false))
        .size(10000));

    System.out.println("Request: " + sr);

    final SearchResponse<MyDoc> response;
    try {
        response = this.esClient.search(sr, MyDoc.class);
    } catch (ElasticsearchException | IOException e) {
        throw new MyException("fetch all ids: request failed: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    System.out.println("Response: " + response);
```

There are no results in the response. However, the printed request is

```
POST /my_index/_search?typed_keys=true {"_source":false,"size":10000}
```

which works perfectly fine when run directly as a REST request.

Any idea how to do it using the Java client?

The REST response is

```json
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 999,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_id": "2LHJSP6dTjXuEM2vsEDyxdG4Y7HPzXL15tFvrkyZm8xn",
        "_score": 1
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_id": "A8RCf2mV4qeWvLxSfzKNX418E734uEifCenoCAiM3syB",
        "_score": 1
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: [Github isue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/issues/473) opened

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works for you:

```
SearchRequest sr = SearchRequest.of(r -> r
    .index("idx_name")
    .source(s -> s.fetch(false))
    .size(10000));

System.out.println("Request: " + sr);

try {
  var response = this.esClient.search(sr, Void.class);
  response.hits().hits().forEach(hit -> {
    System.out.println("ID: " + hit.id());
  });
} catch (ElasticsearchException | IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks but no... Using the Void class is a good idea. Did you try it with success yourself?

Comment: yes, this code works. you want only id document you don't need a dto to map the source once you use source:false.

Comment: Does not work for me. What versions are you using?